# Ruby: My code doesn't pass if I use `.downcase!`

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

I'm trying to complete the "A Night at the Movies" Ruby course on CodeCademy, and encountered a little issue: My code doesn't pass if I use `downcase!` on `choice` and the input is lower-case - if it contains an upper-case letter or is entirely upper-case, it works fine.

Here's my code:

```
movies = {
Foo: "Bar",
}

puts "Commands:"
puts "Add - Add a movie and its rating."
puts "Update - Update a movie's rating."
puts "Display - Display all movies and their ratings."
puts "Delete - Delete a movie and its rating."

choice = gets.chomp.downcase!

case choice
when 'add'
  puts "Added!"
when 'update'
  puts "Updated!"
when 'display'
  puts "Movies!"
when 'delete'
  puts "Deleted!"
else 
  puts "Error!"
end
```

Help?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `#downcase` instead of `#downcase!`.

The reason your code is not passing is because when using `#downcase!` on an already lowercased string, the result returned is `nil`, which is what then gets assigned to your `choice` variable.

Using `#downcase` would return the string itself, even if the provided string is already lowercased.

Hope it helps!